# Best way to develop a test report using Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, logging

I am working on framework using Selenium with Python. Everything seems working just fine, besides test report. So far i was using logging model, but i am not sure if it is good enough in modern automation. 
    I do not use anything by atom to write all components of my data driven framework. So far my framework consist of 3 files:
    1 - setup.py with all of the functions i am using: setup(), teardown() click(), sendKeys() etc. Inside this function i also import logging, and every time i perform any action logging writes to a new file. 
    2 - data.json - moping all of the elements.
    3 - testCase.py - all of the test cases .
    Please advise me how i can improve my framework. Thanks

```
from   selenium import webdriver
from   selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from   selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from   selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import time
import logging
import json

#logging when call writes to log file
logging.basicConfig(filename='tests_Run.log',level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(funcName)s:%(message)s')

#example of logging usage:

def findORclick_element(self, itemInDict ,elemLocator):# This function perform click
        locatorStrategy = elemLocator[:2]
        locator = load_value(itemInDict ,elemLocator)
        ele = None
        try:
            if locatorStrategy == 'id':  # return by ID
                ele =  self.driver.find_element_by_id(locator).click()
                logging.info('  - - Clicked on "{}", - - with value: "{}"'.format(elemLocator, locator))


#this is how logging file output looks like:
2019-06-11 11:53:06,856:INFO:findORclick_element:  - - Clicked on "id_GET_A_QUOTE_NOW", - - with value: "menu-item-188"
2019-06-11 11:53:07,098:INFO:findORclick_element:  - - Clicked on "xp_PRODUCT_LIABILITY", - - with value: "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]/div[1]/p/a"
2019-06-11 11:53:07,392:INFO:send_keys:  - - - - - - - Typed in to "id_COMPANY_NAME", - - with value: "input_41_1"
2019-06-11 11:53:07,576:INFO:send_keys:  - - - - - - - Typed in to "id_DOING_BUSINESS_AS", - - with value: "input_41_3"
2019-06-11 11:53:07,792:INFO:send_keys:  - - - - - - - Typed in to "id_WEBSITE", - - with value: "input_41_92"
2019-06-11 11:53:07,970:INFO:send_keys:  - - - - - - - Typed in to "id_MAILING_ADDRESS_LINE_1", - - with value: "input_41_104"
2019-06-11 11:53:08,070:INFO:send_keys:  - - - - - - - Typed in to "id_ADDRESS_LINE_2", - - with value: "input_41_105"
2019-06-11 11:53:08,249:INFO:send_keys:  - - - - - - - Typed in to "id_CITY", - - with value: "input_41_106"
2019-06-11 11:53:08,294:INFO:findORclick_element:  - - Clicked on "xp_STATE_california", - - with value: "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[7]/div/select/option[6]"
2019-06-11 11:53:08,431:INFO:send_keys:  - - - - - - - Typed in to "id_ZIPCODE", - - with value: "input_41_109"
2019-06-11 11:53:08,554:INFO:send_keys:  - - - - - - - Typed in to "id_CONTACT_NAME_FIRST", - - with value: "input_41_6_3"
2019-06-11 11:53:08,689:INFO:send_keys:  - - - - - - - Typed in to "id_CONTACT_NAME_LAST", - - with value: "input_41_6_6"
```

Comment: Look at [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) & its plugin [pytest-html](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-html) for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Since i am building my Selenium with Python framework from scratch, and not using anything, but Atom to code - after the research, i decided to use following design.

```
from   selenium import webdriver
from   selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from   selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from   selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from   selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from   datetime import datetime
import logging

now = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d---%H-%M-%S')

logging.basicConfig(filename='/test_log-%s.log' % now,
        level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s\n')

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
try:
    driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys('selenium')
    driver.find_element_by_name('btnK').click()
except Exception as e:
    driver.save_screenshot('screenshot-%s.png' % now)
    logging.info(e)
driver.quit()
```

This is how log file looks like, when 'except' block catches an error:

2019-06-13 19:36:41,327:INFO:Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.169)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.14.5 x86_64)